# Function that reverse one part(half) of integer

Tags: c++, c

I want to write a function to reverse one of two parts of number  :

Input is: `num = 1234567; part = 2`
and output is: `1234765`

So here is `part` that can be only 1 or 2

Now I know how to get part 1

```c
int firstPartOfInt(int num) {
    int ret = num;
    digits = 1, halfDig = 10;
    while (num > 9) {
        ret = ret / 10;
        digits++;
    }
    halfDigits = digits / 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < halfDigits; i++) {
        halfDigits *= 10;
    }
    ret = num;
    while (num > halfDigits) {
        ret = ret / 10;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But I don't know how to get part 2 and reverse the number. If you post code here please do not use `vector<>` and other C++ feature not compatible with C

Comment: _And if you post code here please do not use vector<> and other non compatibility features with C_; It would be helpful to fix your tags and to let us know if you use C or C++.

Comment: I use C++ but I dont like containers(exept string) and templates

Comment: @ReQserFirFir i wrote an answer. Please, let me know what you think of it. If it matches your requirements, please upvote and accept. If not, provide me with some feedback

Comment: `other C++ feature not compatible with C` what about C features not compatible with C++? `here is part that can be only 1 or 2` - so why does your function take only one argument, and not two? Why only 3 last digits are inverted, and not like, 6 digits? What is "part 1"/"part 2"? Just `return num % 1000 + num % 10 * 100 + num / 10 % 10 * 10 + num / 100 % 10`?

Comment: @KamilCuk  I need function that just reverse half of number, first or second and that number can be with 7 digits, 100 digits or even 2. And my function return first half from number. Example: input 12345 output 123

Comment: @NutCracker I like work with digits but your answer helps me a 8bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to calculate the total number of digits in the number and then calculate a new number extracting digits from the original number in a certain order, complexity O(number-of-digits):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned reverse_decimal_half(unsigned n, unsigned half) {
    unsigned char digits[sizeof(n) * 3];
    unsigned digits10 = 0;
    do digits[digits10++] = n % 10;
    while(n /= 10);
    unsigned result = 0;
    switch(half) {
    case 1:
        for(unsigned digit = digits10 / 2; digit < digits10; ++digit)
            result = result * 10 + digits[digit];
        for(unsigned digit = digits10 / 2; digit--;)
            result = result * 10 + digits[digit];
        break;
    case 2:
        for(unsigned digit = digits10; digit-- > digits10 / 2;)
            result = result * 10 + digits[digit];
        for(unsigned digit = 0; digit < digits10 / 2; ++digit)
            result = result * 10 + digits[digit];
        break;
    default:
        abort();
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    printf("%u %u %u\n", 0, 1, reverse_decimal_half(0, 1));
    printf("%u %u %u\n", 12345678, 1, reverse_decimal_half(12345678, 1));
    printf("%u %u %u\n", 12345678, 2, reverse_decimal_half(12345678, 2));
    printf("%u %u %u\n", 123456789, 1, reverse_decimal_half(123456789, 1));
    printf("%u %u %u\n", 123456789, 2, reverse_decimal_half(123456789, 2));
}
```

Outputs:

```
0 1 0
12345678 1 43215678
12345678 2 12348765
123456789 1 543216789
123456789 2 123459876
```

Answer (score 0):

if understand this question well you need to reverse half of the decimal number. If the number has odd number of digits I assume that the first part is longer (for example 12345 - the first part is 123 the second 45). Because reverse is artihmetic the reverse the part 1 of `52001234` is `521234`.

https://godbolt.org/z/frXvCM
(some numbers when reversed may wrap around - it is not checked)

```
int getndigits(unsigned number)
{
    int ndigits = 0;
    while(number)
    {
        ndigits++;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return ndigits;
}

unsigned reverse(unsigned val, int ndigits)
{
    unsigned left = 1, right = 1, result = 0;

    while(--ndigits) left *= 10;
    while(left)
    {
        result += (val / left) * right;
        right *= 10;
        val = val % left;
        left /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

unsigned reversehalf(unsigned val, int part)
{
    int ndigits = getndigits(val);
    unsigned parts[2], digits[2], left = 1;

    if(ndigits < 3 || (ndigits == 3 && part == 2))
    {
        return val;
    }

    digits[0] = digits[1] = ndigits / 2;
    if(digits[0] + digits[1] < ndigits) digits[0]++;
    for(int dig = 0; dig < digits[1]; dig++) left *= 10;

    parts[0] = val / left;
    parts[1] = val % left;

    parts[part - 1] = reverse(parts[part - 1], digits[part - 1]);
    val = parts[0] * left + parts[1];

    return val;
}

int main()
{
    for(int number = 0; number < 40; number++)
    {
        unsigned num = rand();
        printf("%u \tpart:%d\trev:%u\n", num,(number & 1) + 1,reversehalf(num, (number & 1) + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My five cents.:)

```
#include <iostream>

int reverse_part_of_integer( int value, bool first_part = false )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    size_t n = 0;

    int tmp = value;

    do
    {
        ++n;        
    } while ( tmp /= Base );

    if ( first_part && n - n / 2 > 1 || !first_part && n / 2 > 1 )
    {
        n = n / 2;
        int divider = 1;

        while ( n-- ) divider *= Base;

        int first_half  = value / divider;
        int second_half = value % divider;

        int tmp = first_part ? first_half : second_half;

        value = 0;

        do
        {
            value = Base * value + tmp % Base;
        } while ( tmp /= Base );

        value = first_part ? value * divider + second_half
                           : first_half * divider +value;
    }

    return value;
}


int main() 
{
    int value = -123456789;

    std::cout << "initial value:        " 
              << value << '\n';

    std::cout << "First part reversed:  " 
              << reverse_part_of_integer( value, true ) << '\n';

    std::cout << "Second part reversed: " 
              << reverse_part_of_integer( value ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
initial value:        -123456789
First part reversed:  -543216789
Second part reversed: -123459876
```

Comment: @P__J__ The function does not use  any feature of C++ that does not exist in C. So your comment does not make sense.

Comment: @P__J__ You may use this name also in C. It is enough to include the corresponding header. Moreover it is not a C++ class.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a solution that counts only half the number of digits before reversing:

```
constexpr int base{10};

constexpr int partial_reverse(int number, int part)
{
    // Split the number finding its "halfway"
    int multiplier = base;
    int abs_number = number < 0 ? -number : number;
    int parts[2] = {0, abs_number};
    while (parts[1] >= multiplier)
    {
        multiplier *= base;
        parts[1] /= base;
    }
    multiplier /= base;    
    parts[0] = abs_number % multiplier;

    // Now reverse only one of the two parts
    int tmp = parts[part];
    parts[part] = 0;
    while (tmp)
    {
        parts[part] = parts[part] * base + tmp % base;
        tmp /= base;
    }

    // Then rebuild the number
    int reversed = parts[0] + multiplier * parts[1];
    return number < 0 ? -reversed : reversed;
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(partial_reverse(123, 0) == 123);
    static_assert(partial_reverse(-123, 1) == -213);
    static_assert(partial_reverse(1000, 0) == 1000);
    static_assert(partial_reverse(1009, 1) == 109);

    static_assert(partial_reverse(123456, 0) == 123654);
    static_assert(partial_reverse(1234567, 0) == 1234765);
    static_assert(partial_reverse(-1234567, 1) == -4321567);
}
```